# What is the name of a matrix displaying all possible combinations of a set (without repetition)?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, terminology

Suppose you have 4 letters: A, B, C, D.

Suppose you want each possible combinations of these letters without repetition: i.e.

{A}, {B}, {C}, {D}, {A,B}, {A,C}, {A,D}, {B,C}, {B,D}, {C,D}, {A,B,C}, {A,B,D}, {A,C,D}, {B,C,D}, {A,B,C,D}

Each combination can be represented by a vector, where the i-th element of the vector takes 1 if the letter is included in the combination, and 0 otherwise. For instance, combinations {A}, {B}, {C}, {D} would be represented respectively as

{1, 0, 0, 0}
{0, 1, 0, 0}
{0, 0, 1, 0}
{0, 0, 0, 1}

By iterating this process, I can create a matrix of this form.

$$
\begin{array}{rrrr}
  \hline
A & B & C & D \\ 
  \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
   \hline
\end{array}
$$

My question is: does this matrix have any known name? Alternatively, is there any known method to formalize how this matrix is produced, so that I can use a general formula to refer to any given row of the matrix?

Note that I am not interested in the order of the rows of the matrix, this can be also random.

Comment: Well, what you are doing is, essentially, representing $\mathcal P(\{A,B,C,D\})$ as $\{0,1\}^{\{A,B,C,D\}}$. While it is clear how you parametrise the columns (essentially, using the elements of th set as index), it is unclear how you parametrise the rows.

Comment: @Gae.S.thank you for you answer. Maybe I wasn't enough clear. Rows does not necessarily need to be organized following a specific order. I used this representation because I thought it was clearer to understand my problem. Order is not important in this system. I just need a name or a notation for a matrix containing all these rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to think about the rows of this matrix is that (after a suitable reordering)  they are the binary representations of the numbers $1, 2, \dots, 2^4 - 1$. If we included the empty set, its row (which would be all zeroes) would be the binary representation of $0$. Various ways to get the binary representations of numbers are your best way to get the $i^{\text{th}}$ row of the matrix in terms of $i$.

If you just want to generate *all* the rows, your best bet is a recursive strategy. To get the $2^n$ rows for the $n$-column case (including the zero row), take two copies of the $(n-1)$-column matrix. Add a $0$ in the $n^{\text{th}}$ column of the first copy, and a $1$ in the $n^{\text{th}}$ column of the second copy.

Most applications don't actually treat this table as a matrix. But you see it in error-correcting codes: if we take the transpose (so that we have $n$ rows and $2^n-1$ columns) then the result is the parity check matrix of the [Hamming code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code), or equivalently the generator matrix of the [Hadamard code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_code#Construction_using_a_generator_matrix). (For these applications, the order of your rows/their columns is not terribly important either, though you want to pick an order and stick to it, so you'll see various permutations.)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. This is useful information. If I understand correctly these names come from coding theory. My question was whether the matrix had a name in a broader mathematical framework, but this is for sure a good starting point. I agree with you that I should stick with an order of the matrix. But since I do not need one in particular, I didn't ask for one, so to increase the chances to find someone able to answer.

Comment: Yes, the names are from coding theory. There's no widely recognized name, though, or else the coding theorists would probably have used it! I don't guarantee that no other area of math has a name for this matrix, but it's probably similarly specific in that case.

Comment: This is actually a good point. Thus, if nothing comes up (e.g. a name known in a wider field of mathematics) in the next few days, I will accept your answer as correct.